# Combine 2 android apps

Tags: android, integration

Experts,

I am having the source code of 2 android apps which have been separately developed. I need to combine both of them as a single application so the output would be a single apk file. Let me more specific.

1. App 1: Shop list app -
2. App 2 Calculator app.

using a button click in the App 1 I would want to call the second app Calculator. I have researched on Internet and I am seeing some suggestions like library project etc.

Anyone who has some idea on the feasiblity, please throw some ideas on the same.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1):

> output would be a single apk file.

Then use as a library project.

Check this may help you

- [Setting up a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)
- [Referencing a library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse-> right click on your project-> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Go to "Projects" tabs on Top and add new project which will install two apks of the curernt project and the depends project that you just added.

It will do the trick for you.

Thanks