# Combine android projects together

Tags: android, android-activity, project

I want to combine 2 android projects together in such a way that when an button is pressed from one activity (of 1st project ) it should start my activity from (2nd project)
both the projects are fully functional applications.. it is just that they were developed in parts
i tried a lot of searches entire but ended up being frustated
can someone provide me with a simple way to do so

the activity i am trying to call is

> MainActivity.java 
>   from 2nd project
>   when a button is pressed from activity in first project

i want to combine the projects together..so that i can export it as a single apk...

Comment: Isn't the Intent what you're looking for? You can call any activity using its class name.

Comment: noeps..thats the issue...i cant call it using intents as they are in diffrent projects

Comment: But it's the purpose of intents. You can call the gmail app, the gallery, the image viewer, the browser, although all of them are in another project.

Comment: i tried it using intent a lot...googled a lot too...but every time i get force close.. MainActivity.class cannot be found....

Comment: Does MainActivity.java class exists in both the projects??

Comment: no and i want to combine the projects together..so that i can export it as a single apk...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950677/combine-2-android-apps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on what you intend to do with the projects.

If you wish to merge the project into a single app , at least one of them should be set as an android library , and another project should use it . This way , the merged projects would be able to recognize each other .

If you wish to have 2 apps and not a single app , each activity that you wish to access from another activity should have a special definition in the manifest (using intent filter) of how to open it , as it's not the default behavior .

Comment: well you choose a project , choose its properties , go to the "android" category , and choose that it is a libary . Then , you go to the other project that should use it , and go to the same place but you choose to add a library . do note that all resources are also merged , so if you have a drawable file in the library project called "image2.png" and the same file in the project that uses this library , only one will be used (the one from the project that uses the library)  . also , you should change the manifest so that it could handle the activities from the library.

Comment: i got the error fixed...still confused..how to call the activity from library

Comment: after you merge the projects , you will be able to call the activity as if it was a part of the project that uses the library . nothing special .

Comment: i tried, it worked...I get the MainActivity.java Screen .....however if i click futhur(there is a button on the activity which invokes other activity from same project) it force closes and get an error msg    01-17 21:54:06.171: E/dalvikvm(10925): Could not find class 'com.rahul.example.PlacesMapActivity', referenced from method com.rahul.example.MainActivity$1.onClick

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to show a new `MainActivity` instance you need to declare an intent-filter in your "2nd project" manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="your.package.here.MainActivity" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Then create an intent with the same action string in your first project:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("your.package.here.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i was searching through some post...and it said to mark it as a library..and use it..still didnt get how to do that                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950677/combine-2-android-apps