# how to combine two android studio projects into one

Tags: java, android

I have one sinch project for  messaging and my own project for chat, I want to integrate both project for my application. Please help me out. I'm not getting satisfied answers. I am asking about SINCH MESSAGING CHAT. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate. You're looking for library project

Answer (score 0):

From [Combine android projects together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978414/combine-android-projects-together)

> The answer depends on what you intend to do with the projects.
>
> If you wish to merge the project into a single app , at least one of
>   them should be set as an android library , and another project should
>   use it . This way , the merged projects would be able to recognize
>   each other .
>
> If you wish to have 2 apps and not a single app , each activity that
>   you wish to access from another activity should have a special
>   definition in the manifest (using intent filter) of how to open it ,
>   as it's not the default behavior .

Comment: I've mentioned that i want to integrate my application with sinch messaging chat.

Comment: Isn't is possible to have the messaging chat as an android library? Or do you want to merge the projects including all non java files such as graphics and xml views?

Comment: i think you are asking about my project description