# Is it possible to create one APK from two different android applications source trees?

Tags: android, gradle, build-system

I received this nice task, the idea is to build one single APK from what normally are two separate apps.
So for instance, I have the whole source trees for two apps, AppA and AppB and I want to create AppC by 'merging' together these two source sets.
Please note that AppA and AppB are not libraries, they are regular Android apps.
I've never done something like this and have no idea if gradle allows this, probably yes, but I don't know where to start.
Is there anyone out there who ever did this?

Comment: try [Product Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors)

Comment: sorry that doesn't help.. can you explain more please?

Comment: what do u mean by merging together ?? like lets say there is splash screens in both apps so your end app should have two splash screens ??

Comment: Is the aim one combined app that does all the functions of the two component apps, or one installation package that installs two separate apps at the same time? The former is likely to be a large amount of non-trivial work; no idea whether the second is possible.

Comment: The idea is the first one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978414/combine-android-projects-together does this help? or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33559465/5746918

Comment: Yes.. well, the only idea I can come up with for this is actually using libraries. What you posted here seems to confirm that there is no way to just merge two application projects. Thanks.