# How to merge two applications?

Tags: android

I am developing an Answering Machine application.

Basically it has to automatically accept the call, give a voice message and start recording the call.

I have designed an application to automatically answer to calls and another application to record calls. Individually both the apps work fine. But after i merged them the application crashes.

I saw a an example here :[Combine 2 android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950677/combine-2-android-apps). I merged the apps same way but still the application crashes.

How can I properly merge my apps?

Comment: If you want people to help you with a crash, you should post the crashlog and the code that's causing it.

Comment: i think android os security system dos not allow kind of this operations.

Comment: cut the code of "automatically answer to calls " app and paste it into "application to record calls." also check the permissions of both the apps. this may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.example.package", "com.example.package.ActivityToStart");
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package");
startActivity(intent);
```

to invoke 2 apps. And retrieve files from their default save location.